# Entity Framework Code First Seed From Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I know how to write some seed code for my app, but I'd love to be able to create the data using the site and then have the seed code generated with the data from the DB.  Is this possible?  Anything that generates the seed code for you based on the database?

```
ApplicationPermission appPerm1 = new ApplicationPermission();
appPerm1.Name = "Admin";
appPerm1.PermissionCode = Guid.Parse("32BEDDD6-D52D-4DF6-AD2D-6740CC8C01F3");
context.ApplicationPermissions.Add(appPerm1);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You have problems with the context? You want to seed database manually? Once or once in a while?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't sound like a great idea but if you really want to do it you could:

Write a SQL script that will generate the appropriate C# syntax and use the result of that query to paste into your .cs Seed file.

However, if you just want random test data; RedGate have a tool that will generate realistic looking data. http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/

If you just want some specific test data, I'd suggest taking the one off hit and writing the seed data manually.

Comment: Thanks for the Red Gate recommendation...  Essentially I'm working on a CRM and the idea of creating 1000 customer records via c# code is really not attractive.

Comment: Eeek, yeah we had to do that a while back, one guy created a random data generator and then we found the RedGate tools. They do a great job of putting enough data in there to satisfy most test cases (especially if it's exploratory testing) - The trial version is worth a shot